# How do I get this value from my html in Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have this element on my html page:

```
    <div class="section-title" id="bladeSectionTitle"
         ng-transclude="title">
    </div>
```

I want to get the value displayed.

I have tried the following in my typescript page & only get null:

```
     var title = document.getElementById("bladeSectionTitle").getAttribute('section-title');
```

The view source gives me this:

```
    <dpn-blade-section is-checkbox-visible="true" is-checked="$component.showAll">
        <section-title>
            <h4>Show All</h4>
        </section-title>
```

In this instance, the value I would be looking for is 'Show All'.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of angular are you running? We really need more information here. Although accessing the DOM directly isn't the way to go with angular, you're looking at something like this

`var title = document.querySelector('dpn-blade-section section-title h4').innerHTML;`